# How to implement .includes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, include, chatbot, contains

I'm developing a very simple chatbot using JS and HTML, and I have the following code which outputs an "answer" as a reply to what the user has asked. This works fine but when I try to implement *.includes* to check if a certain phrase has been asked it no longer outputs anything. For example, if the user asks "can you help" it should output the same answer as "help" since it contains the "help" keyword. Without *.includes* the code works fine.

```
function talk() {

  var know = {
    "Hey": "Hello!",
    "Help": `You can find help by clicking <a href='https://addressname.com'target="_blank">here</a>`
  };

  var user = document.getElementById('userBox').value;
  
  document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML = user + "<br>";
  
  if (user in know) {
    document.getElementById.includes('chatLog').innerHTML = know[user] + "<br>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML = "I do not understand.";
  }

}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a function. It expects to be called with a parameter (`document.getElementById("#selector")`). It has no `.includes` property. If you simply open your console, it will tell you very clearly : `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById.includes is not a function`. So you don't even need to ask a question about it on Stackoverflow :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change below line

```
document.getElementById.includes('chatLog').innerHTML
```

as

```
document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML.includes(user)
```

The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

Hope this helps: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

**Update:**

```
    var know = {
  "Hey": "Hello!",
  "Help": `You can find help by clicking <a href='https://addressname.com' target="_blank">here</a>`
};

function goo() {
  var userBox = document.getElementById('userBox');
  var userInput = userBox.value;
  var chatLog = document.getElementById('chatLog');
  var chatLogContent = "";

  if (!userInput) {
    chatLogContent = 'Please enter some value'
  }

  var hasKeyword = false;

  for (var key in know) {
    if (userInput.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())) {
      hasKeyword = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (hasKeyword) {
    chatLogContent += know[key] + "<br>"; //or use know.key
  } else {
    chatLogContent += "I do not understand.<br>";
  }

  var client = document.createElement('div');
  client.setAttribute('class', 'client');
  client.innerHTML += userInput + "<br>";

  chatLog.appendChild(client);

  var server = document.createElement('div');
  server.setAttribute('class', 'server');
  server.innerHTML = chatLogContent;

  chatLog.appendChild(server);

}
```

**Update**

This should be helpful: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/smileyface/948bg03n/1/ 
Well, I am not good at css. But it works perfectly. Scroll through each time you click on button.
*Try here - Localhost chat box is here* : https://jsfiddle.net/smileyface/948bg03n/1/show

**Update**
As you asked in comment,
This will only show current comments

```
if(hasKeyword){
    chatLogContent = know[key] + "<br>"; //or use know.key
}else{
    chatLogContent = "I do not understand.<br>";
}

chatLog.innerHTML = chatLogContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried this but unfortunately it only outputs what the user has typed as opposed to the "answer".

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean to write exact code for your application. Just thought to provide the clarification on the mistake you made. Please go through the mozilla website for getting more understanding on `.includes`

Comment: @user1300788 , I have updated the answer. Please go through and let me know if it does not works. I didnt tried in my machine.

Comment: @smileyface it works great, thank you very much for the help. I appreciate it and I'll be sure to go through the resources you've linked.

Comment: @smileyface this line "Help": `You can find help by clicking <a href='https://addressname.com' target="_blank">here</a>` seems to cause it to break. It displays "I do not understand" as well as the answer

Comment: @user1300788 - check my JSFiddle (link)

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a ton! How can I clear the chatLog? I want it to only show the current message instead of a history

Comment: @smiley chatLog.empty().appendChild(server); I've attempted this but still not having any luck

Comment: Create a button "clear", onClick call a function with content `chatLog.innerHTML = "";` then `chatLog.appendChild(server)` or `client`

Comment: @user1300788, updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

The includes() method determines **whether an array includes** a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

Also **getElementById is a function** which expects the id of an element as a parameter.

If you want to change the inner HTML of an element having id `chatLog` then you have to do it the following way.

```
if (user in know) {
    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML = know[user] + "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the clarification